# A function $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$ $\iff$ it can be defined on $\{a, b\}$ such that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

A Theorem regarding Uniform Continuity states :

> A function $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$ $\iff$ It can be defined on the endpoints $a$, $b$ such that $f$ is continuous on the $[a,b]$.

Now  I have a doubt regarding this ,especially regarding the use of   ''$\iff$ '' here.

Suppose we have the function $f:\Bbb R\to[-1,1]$ $$f(x)=sgn(x)=\begin{cases} 1,&x>0 \\0,&x=0\\-1,&x<0\end{cases}$$
[image]
So here I'm choosing a open interval $A$ from it's domain, which is $(0,1)$. So the endpoints of  $A$ are $0$ and $1$ , (i.e. $\bar A=[0,1])$ .
Here f(x) is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$ . But at the endpoint 0 is it really continuous ? We can see the $sgn(x)$ function is continuous everywhere except at $x=0$.So instead of not being continuous everywhere in $[0,1]$ , $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on$(0,1)$.

So now my question is that how can the statement__ $\text{if $f$ can be defined on the endpoints a,b such that $f$ is continuous on the [a,b] } \implies $$\text{ $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on (a,b)} $
?

Thank You.

**N.B:** First of all , all kinds of responses are welcome . Secondly I don't know whether this question has asked before in this platform of not but I have no intention to copy or duplicate any one's question .

Comment: "can be defined at the endpoints" in particular allows changing its value at the endpoints if it was already defined there. If you re-define $f(0)=1$ then $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: But $f(0)=0$ already ... how can I get 2 different image points for a single point in in the domain? isn't it against the definition of a function ?

Comment: I've made significant edits to your title (to make it readable) and have reformatted your theorem to make it readable.  It is possible I have altered the meaning while doing so, so please check and correct errors I may have introduced.

Comment: Eric Towers thank you.. your edits have no negative impact on my question.

Comment: @DebjitMullick But that's what the theorem means, that you change its value. You re-define $f(0)=1$. There is only a single value, not two.

Comment: Said another way, on $(0, 1)$, the signum function is identically $1$; its unique continuous extension to $[0, 1]$ is also identically $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to read the theorem is:

$f:(a, b) \to \Bbb R$ is uniformly continuous $\iff \exists \tilde f:[a, b] \to \Bbb R$ such that $\tilde f$ is continuous and $\forall x \in (a, b) f(x)=\tilde f(x)$.

In other words, $\tilde f$ extends $f$ to a function that's continuous on $[a, b]$.

The function you're defining isn't limited to being continuously defined on $(0,t)$, so the theorem has nothing to say about it.  The theorem does speak about restrictions of your function to non-negative domains.

Comment: Thank you sir ... I think this is a better explanation..